# I Get An Access Token/Id Token From Azure AD Using OIDC - Can I Create And Endpoint To Issue My Own JWT?

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, openid-connect

I have implemented OIDC Auth2 using an Azure AD Application Registration and successfully get a token that can be validated by my web API (with .NetCore backend and VUE front end). This token however does not have the required information I need in it to login to some endpoints of the app ie. that require the role claim.

Is it legitimate to create an authorized endpoint that returns a JWT (like the existing password grant) to exchange for this token?

Comment: Why not add the required information in a claim in the app registration?

Comment: Because it can be configured dynamically via my app (its not a static value)

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't like the additional endpoint idea which is why i kept researching and found you can add claims dynamically using the OnTokenValidated request - this is what I ended up using:

```
options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
                {                     
                    // I swap this out for getting the claims from dbo.AspNetUserRoles
                    var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "superadmin") };

                    // Create a new claims identity
                    var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

                    // Add the identity to the principle
                    ctx.Principal?.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                }
            };
```